# What is a proper n-etale morphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, higher-category-theory, stacks, orbifolds

Let $Y$ be a complex algebraic variety, and let $n\in \mathbb Z_{\geq 1}\cup \{\infty\}$. How do I think about a proper $n$-etale morphism $X\to Y$?

If $n=1$, I think this should be a finite etale morphism (in the category of varieties).

If $n=2$,  examples are $G$-gerbes over $Y$.

Do elements in $H^n(Y,G)$ give rise to proper $n$-etale morphisms $X\to Y$?

Comment: Could you define n-etale morphism?

Comment: Perhaps Monsie means a locally trivial sheaf/stack/higher stack of n-1 truncated and n-1 connective sets/groupoids/higher groupoids?

Comment: @JoeBerner Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I don't think I can really answer your question, but you should read the preface of Higher Topos Theory. He talks about exactly this question there, and has some references http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf